# Run an SQL Query With a Parameter from Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, sql-server-2008, sql, query

I have a query in an Excel table.  I followed [this](https://superuser.com/questions/193258/how-do-i-write-a-query-in-microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-and-then-use-tha/193299#193299) to do it.

But how can I add a parameter from a cell into my query?

I am looking for a way to do this:

```
select *
from dbo.Customers
where CustomerID = Cell.A2
```

The **Cell.A2** does not work. But how can I add in something like it, so that the contents of a cell are used in my query?

Comment: Have you tried just naming the cell - then using the name in the query instead of the cell reference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Dunno why MS has made this so complicated, You will have to use Microsoft Query.

Click on Data -> From External Sources -> From Microsoft Query. CHoose Data source comes up. Select SQL Server, enter the Auth details, and select the table

[image]

Click on Next, don't select any filtering criteria, choose sort by criteria, click on next. 
Now, click on View/Edit in MS Query instead of selecting Return to Excel

[image]

Click on Finish. Now in MS Query, Click on Criteria -> Add Criteria, choose the operator and let the value be `[]`

[image]

Click on File -> return data to Excel. Now Excel should prompt you for the parameter, select the relevant cell

[image]

To edit the parameters, click on Data -> Properties -> Finger icon -> Definition -> parameters

[image]

---

You can also use the SQL query editor and type in the query with the joins and put a `?` against the field where the parameter has to be fetched.

[image]

Comment: Alas, parameters is disabled.

Comment: @Vaccano: Revamped my answer, please have a look

Comment: Thanks for the effort on this Sathya. Alas I realized that because my query has some joins in it MS Query cannot display it graphically.  That makes it so you cannot have parameters.  I am going to make it as a VBA function.  I am giving you the nod though because your answer was so complete.

Comment: @Vaccano: You can write the query using the SQL editor, and put a `?` against the field to which the parameter has to be selected http://i.imgur.com/NgXxc.png

Comment: I have found that once the query is in Excel, you can go into the query parameters screen and edit it there without going into MS Query again.  Just drop a ? where the criteria goes.  Then go back into the connection properties screen and assign that parameter to a cell in the spreadsheet.

Comment: @Tracy yeah, that works as well!

Comment: Where all the images go?

Comment: @slotishtype fixed. Side effect of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95732/images-manually-uploaded-to-imgur-are-not-displaying/95734#comment-240583)

Answer (score 1):

*It's never too late for a shameless plug...*

There's this [great little plugin](http://thingiequery.com) for Excel...(disclaimer: I'm the author)

It's an Excel plugin that adds a database engine and an SQL IDE to Excel.

It lets you do SQL operations on anything that is marked as a table inside Excel. You can query across workbooks, and also use tables from an external database (SQL Server/Sqlite/Postgres/Access/MySql) in the same query.

It has SQL syntax highlighting, statement completion and a bunch of other cool stuff. It uses SQLite under the hood, but can use external db engines to process the data as well.

I do charge for it tho, but there's a free trial which you can use for 30 days. It's called ThingieQuery.

Sorry about the plug, hopefully it's not too inappropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Put value as

```
where employeecode = '?'
```

This will enable your parameter button, but when you press ok it will prompt you.