# Embed microsoft query in excel with multiple parameters from spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, sql, query, parameters

I am trying to embed a microsoft query within an excel spreadsheet, that passes several parameters from the spreadsheet to the query.  I would like the microsoft excel query function to find a few values in cells on the worksheet and pass them into the SQL code.  I used [this](https://superuser.com/questions/197453/run-an-sql-query-with-a-parameter-from-excel-2007/318647#318647) approach, but I could only understand how to pass a single parameter using the ?. I would like to pass about 3 or 4 parameters, and some of them are used in multiple places in the query.  The query doesn't seem to be editable using the query builder in ms query so I wrote it in sql using a text editor.

Note: other than SQL select queries, I'm not much of a programmer so if there is a point and click way to do this (i.e. something that does not require visual basic) that would be especially helpful.

Comment: This is very trivial to do with VBA.  Without it, I'm not sure how unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in SQL view, then Excel will prompt you to select the referring cells:

```
where (CustomerID = ?) AND (xxx = ?) AND (zzz = ?)
```