# Dynamic field names in Excel queries

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql-server, power-query

As [explained here](https://superuser.com/questions/197453/run-an-sql-query-with-a-parameter-from-excel-2007), Excel queries accept dynamic values (e.g. "where name = ?" and "?" can be linked to a cell of your choice).

Alas, Excel queries don't seem to accept dynamic field names (e.g. the "name" in "where name"). Is there a way to bypass that limitation? Well, another way [than this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855796/cant-capture-strings-in-the-select-of-where-select).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  I first add an Index column, then duplicate the Query.

In the duplicate, I would select the Index and choose Unpivot Columns / Unpivot Other Columns (PQ Transform ribbon).  This will convert each cell into a row, with Attribute (field name) and Value columns.

I would then filter on the Attribute and Value fields, which would give you a list of which Index values to keep.

Then I would return to the original query, and use Merge Queries (PQ Home ribbon) to join it to the duplicated query, matching on the Index columns and using the Join Kind: Inner.